# Could session_start() in php be messing up my users sessions lengths?

Tags: php, apache

My php.ini file is set to expire sessions within 24 hours.  But my users complain after being logged out after just 20 minutes or so.

I use session_start at the beginning of every page.  Could that be messing things up for me?
Or could there be anything else causing this?

Just realized I might be on a shared hosting.  And it might have some group settings for garbage collection with sessions.  Anyone know how to look into this or set mine to be more specific?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to use session_start() at the beginning of a script otherwise you won't be able to access the session data.

Comment: @Kenneth I use session_start at the beginning of every script.

Comment: that is correct and that is what you're supposed to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime',28800);  #28800 - just an example time - set your own
ini_set('session.gc_probability',1);
ini_set('session.gc_divisor',1);
session_save_path('/path to your sessions folder');
ob_start();
session_start();
```

You do need to create a session folder first.
This works for sure on GoDaddy shared hosting. 
On VPS you can use this or just update your php.ini file.

Comment: @AR I updated my php.ini and for some reason when I do phpinfo the new changes do show up, but I am not sure why the session expires. :(

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php     If different scripts have different values of session.gc_maxlifetime but share the same place for storing the session data then the script with the minimum value will be cleaning the data. In this case, use this directive together with session.save_path.   Could that be the case?

Comment: @AR What other scripts could possibly have the session.gc_maxlifetime value? Btw, ideally I'd like to keep all the settings in the configs instead of code. But there is definitely something cleaning out my sessions and setting them to zero size.

Comment: Your session.cookie_lifetime value is much smaller than session timeout. Not sure if that's the problem, but maybe try to set the same value or set it to "0" (until the browser is closed)    http://blogs.oracle.com/oswald/entry/php_session_gc_maxlifetime_vs

Answer (score 2):

Check `phpinfo()` to see what the settings really are. PHP has multiple .ini files, and its settings can be overridden in multiple places, so your session session may not be the ones actually in effect. phpinfo's output will show what the "Local" this-is-now-whats-in-effect settings are.

Beyond that, session_start() won't delete a session itself, but it MAY trigger a session garbage collector run based on a few `gc_*` .ini settings. It's a probabilistic thing, though, and won't happen every time you start a session.

Another possibility is that your session files are going into a system temp directory somewhere, and something external to PHP is cleaning up that directory at 20 minute intervals. So check what the `session.save_path` setting is and see if anything's cleaning up that location.

Comment: @Marc yeah I think since I am on a shared hosting plan, I might be sharing the session gc configs.  Do you know how to set mine to be unique?

Comment: Actually I am not on shared hosting.  I am on VPS

Comment: I have session.gc_maxlifetime = 200000 but obviously that isnt being listened to by my application :)

Comment: Is that 200,000 what's coming out of phpinfo(), or what you've put into php.ini? Only what phpinfo() says matters. You could try putting a `php_value session.gc_maxlifetime = 200000` into a .htaccess in the root of your site, but doing it via php.ini would be preferable.

Comment: Looks ok, I'd check if there's a cron job cleaning up the session cache dir.

Comment: @Marc by the way, what is the session cache dir usually?

Comment: `/var/lib/php/session`, from `session.save_path`