# $_SESSION empty after roughly 10 min's in PHP

Tags: php, session

We currently use $_SESSION for our current session data (ie, login, current state, etc, etc). And the script worked perfectly fine for ages, but we changed from an old PHP4 server to a PHP5 server. Now after a certain amount of time (roughly 10 mins, but it doesn't seem to be consistent) the $_SESSION gets wiped! (:O!). But it appears as if the PHPSESSID is still residing in the cookies, so the cookie doesn't seem to expire...

My servers current settings are: (phpinfo)

http://jsfiddle.net/6DjcC/1/

What could be causing this? I'm sure its something small I've totally over looked and is the primary cause.

My session variables:

```
Directive   Local Value Master Value
session.auto_start  Off Off
session.bug_compat_42   On  On
session.bug_compat_warn On  On
session.cache_expire    15400   15400
session.cache_limiter   nocache nocache
session.cookie_domain   no value    no value
session.cookie_httponly Off Off
session.cookie_lifetime 0   0
session.cookie_path /   /
session.cookie_secure   Off Off
session.entropy_file    /dev/urandom    /dev/urandom
session.entropy_length  0   0
session.gc_divisor  100 100
session.gc_maxlifetime  154000  154000
session.gc_probability  0   0
session.hash_bits_per_character 5   5
session.hash_function   0   0
session.name    PHPSESSID   PHPSESSID
session.referer_check   no value    no value
session.save_handler    files   files
session.save_path   /var/lib/php    /var/lib/php
session.serialize_handler   php php
session.use_cookies On  On
session.use_only_cookies    On  On
session.use_trans_sid   0   0
```

I am using the following "non-standard extensions":

-X-Debug

-Suhosin

-eAccelerator

Answer (score 1):

My bet is that other applications are wiping out your session. They seem to share the same session save_path.

Thy changing your save_path using [session_save_path()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.session-save-path.php).

Comment: I've performed the change. Ill report back if it works or not, and mark answer accordingly. In the mean time, is there anything else it could be?

Comment: Just doesn't work, doesn't seem to hold the variables for longer than a few seconds now :|

Answer (score 0):

Are you on a shared hosting? If yes, try to change session.save_path: [Could session_start() in php be messing up my users sessions lengths?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6471431/could-session-start-in-php-be-messing-up-my-users-sessions-lengths)

Comment: No sorry, dedicated server. Although several vhosts.